# Restore SVN revisions from local copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My SVN server crashed yesterday. I have restoried it from a cloud copy, but the copy was made three days ago. Sine the copy was made I did about 6-8 commits. So, for example, a file version in my local copy is 6119, but the last versin on the server is 6115. Can I resore revisions from my local copy somehow? Or some other advices what to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Can I resore revisions from my local copy somehow?

No. Working copy doesn't have history - Subversion is a centralized VCS. You can commit your current WC into restored repo, but you'll get all intermediate changes in missing in repo revisions collapsed into one (last)

Comment: I cant do a commit for the changes 6115-6119. When I try to commit it shows me that there is no changes. I think its becuse local file's revisions are older than on the server.